# Can't Find winforms.dll for ReportViewer v12 for VS2015

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015, report-viewer2012

I just imported a VS2010 project into VS2015 but I am receiving some errors on ReportViewer 2012 when referencing to winforms.dll version 2012.

I did installed the runtime version 2015 from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496

Now, I can not find the newer dll for the reportviewer.winforms. I am not sure if this is the right installation file needed for Visual Studio 2015.  Can someone help? - Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of adding references from `Add Reference ...`, you can put a `ReportViewer` control on a `Form` and it will add required references to `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms`

Answer (score 2):

Since it was not available yet, I created a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.VS2015.WinForms) for it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a nuget package now. Your best bet is to remove the reference and re-add it via the nuget package manager.

Comment: Thanks Jeff :)

I found it and reinstall it using the nuget manager as you requested.

Comment: but now it seems I have the same amount of errors while I can verify that the references are there. :(

Comment: I see the problem..... it installed the reference for webforms not winforms.  When I look inside the package folder, I do not see the winforms.dll :(

Comment: It's a different nuget package for winforms

Comment: I found its a separate package and the lastest one is Version 10.0.40

Comment: I believe there is a newer one as well